# How to iterate a "Related Links" using C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco

I'm having trouble using the umbraco default datatype "related links". My problem is that I want to iterate the property's children/options. I've seen examples using xml and xslt but I'm wondering if there's any possibilty to use pure c# inside a User Control.

Something like this (But a working variant)

```
Node node = new Node(Node.getCurrentNodeId());
var linklist = node.GetProperty("link");
if (node.GetProperty("link") != null)
{
    foreach (var item in linklist)
    { 
        //get each item here
    }
}
```

Thanks!

(I've also posted the question [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/36007-How-to-iterate-a-Related-Links-using-C))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what i did to make it work. I used Jorge's answer but changed it a little, very little. By the help of looking in the umbraco.config this is how i did

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@using umbraco.NodeFactory;
@{
var root = Model;
var links = root.link;
if (links == null)
{
    return;
}
foreach(var item in links)
{
    DynamicNode linkNode = Model.NodeById(@item.link);
    Response.Redirect(@linkNode.Url);
    break;
}
}
```

I think I could have used a little of Derek's asnwer in a usercontrol. By that i mean i could have selected the property as usual and the used XmlTextReader to read the xml-part of the selected property. Thanks for your halp!

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be able to do something like this (Razor)

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@{
    var root = Model.AncestorOrSelf();
    var links = root.FooterLinks.link;
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><span>@Dictionary.RelatedLinks</span></li>
    @foreach (var item in links)
    {
        var url = item.type == "internal" ? Library.NodeById(item.link).Url : item.link;
        var rel = item.type == "external" ? " rel=\"external\"" : string.Empty;
        var title = item.title;
        <li><a href="@url"@Html.Raw(rel)>@title</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know of XML Serialization / De-Serialization?

I would research this area, It will allow you to read through XML data easier, by de-serializing your XML into C# Objects such as Lists of Arrays.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Hope this is of use.